# ecto select fields with map function as alias or different name

Tags: sql, elixir, alias, ecto

```
iex(18)> fields = [:id]                                                                  
[:id]

iex(19)> fields_map = %{id: :job_id}                                                     
%{id: :job_id}

iex(20)> query = from p in Qber.V1.JobModel, where: p.id == 1, select: map(p, ^fields)
#Ecto.Query<from j in Qber.V1.JobModel, where: j.id == 1, select: map(j, [:id])>
```

I want to select my fields dynamically with **AS names** on the basis of params I got(which may have some joins as this app is going to have heavy admin dashboard queries). So I need dynamic solution. is there a way I can pass a map instead of list dynamically to *map function* and ecto will send me the selected result with custom names I passed in map. Instead of

```
[%{id: 1}]
```

I want the result to be

```
[%{job_id: 1}]
```

*Note*: I have tried and searched different keywords on the web and I have gone through almost all the docs many times and unable to find solution.

Comment: `Ecto.Query<from j in Qserv.V1.JobModel, where: j.id == 1,
 select: %{job_id: j.id}>/` May be you are looking  something like this?Its not dynamic but accepts a map and custom key to assign the value

Comment: I need dynamic solution. I already knew this way. Thanks btw

Comment: Post with complete context: https://elixirforum.com/t/ecto-select-fields-with-map-function-as-alias-or-different-name/13106